# Salvar Imagem c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Estou tendo o seguinte erro **Erro genérico de GDI+.** ao tentar salvar a imagem em um determinado diretório especifico. Estou usando código abaixo.

```
string caminho=@"\\\10.1.1.10\\sistema";
            Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog abrir = new OpenFileDialog();
        abrir.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        abrir.FilterIndex = 1;
        abrir.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (abrir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = abrir.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                   using (myStream)
                   {
                    Bitmap imagem = new Bitmap(abrir.FileName);//Pega o nome do arquivo escolhido
                    Bitmap igm = new Bitmap(imagem, 119, 110);//Padronisa o tamanho da imagaem ao picturebox
                    ImagemCamera.Image = igm;
                    ImagemCamera.Image.Save(caminho + "\\Fotos" + "\\" + Foto + "\\" + FotoId + ".Png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                 }
       }
```

alguém pode ajudar-me?

Comment: O que é `ImagemCamera`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Obrigado por perguntar. é o nome de meu picturebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem se você chegou até aqui louco por uma resposta. Algumas horas depois eu tive a seguinte conclusão.
na linha onde salva o picturebox, que no meu caso recebe no nome de **ImagemCamera**, ficaria assim

```
ImagemCamera.Image.Save(Path.GetFullPath(caminho) + "\\Fotos" + "\\" + Foto + "\\" + FotoId + ".Png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```